# Como cargar una página mediante un .bat y luego cerrarla

Tags: chrome, .bat

Tengo un archivo .bat que inicia lo siguiente: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost/PruebasApiRest/ClienteApiRest.php. Esto lo tengo programado con una Tarea de Windows. Pero mi problema es que a medida que se va ejecutando este bat, me van quedando activas instancias del chrome que ya fué ejecutado. La pregunta es: hay alguna forma de, por ejemplo al cabo de un determinado tiempo, eliminar la tarea creada?

Desde ya, muchas gracias y hasta otro contacto.

Comment: Me parece que tu problema se podría resolver con un sistema de automatización como [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev). Si bien la mayoría de las implementaciones que [hay por internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+webdriver) son con Python, también se [puede con PHP](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mantenerte dentro de bat deberías poder hacerlo con `taskkill /IM "process name" /F`

No tengo un windows a mano pero diría que poniendo `chrome.exe` como process name se cargaría el chrome.

Si quieres matar solo una pestaña en vez del navegador no se si es posible

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, efectivamente, se cierra el chrome completo, todas las pestañas que estén abiertas. Si bien no es lo que quería pero se acerca bastante.